# How is this simple gap achieved?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting started with Bootstrap, and HTML in general.

Looking at the [homepage for Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html), what causes this ~50px gap between the `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">`, and the following `<div class="container">`?

[image]

I've explored the DOM structure in chrome, and  can't see which element causes the gap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's caused by the `padding-top` property of the `body` element, currently set at 90px.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a 90px of padding-top applied to the body element.

The reason they have done this is because the top bar is a fixed element, and to make sure the rest of the page does not hide underneath when the page loads a padding-top is applied to push the rest of the page down.